# Removing BIOS password on Lenovo Ideapad 130-15ikb 81h7

Tags: bios, passwords, reset

I set a BIOS password on my Lenovo Ideapad 130-15ikb 81h7 computer. Normally I save all of my passwords securely but for this one, I somehow have no idea of what it is.

How do I remove it?

Comment: You don't (old methods that may have worked for old BIOS aren't applicable to UEFI). The best you can do is contact tech support and provide some proof of ownership. Very likely it'll imply changing the whole motherboard at your expense.

Comment: As above. You need the password to remove the password

Comment: Only Lenovo Support can help with such a problem.